# A FPGA Project Proposal where I can use both PS and PL

Tags: embedded, fpga, vivado, hdmi, soc

I need to do a project at the undergraduate level. I will design an embedded system project using the Pynq Z1/Z2 FPGA board. So, I need to use both the PS and PL. Can you suggest a project for me? Let it be something easy to moderate level, as I am not very experienced.

I really can't think of anything. The project won't involve PCB or any camera module. Could you also specify in the suggested project which part will be done through PS and which part will be done through PL?

What I have in mind is to invert the colors of the video transferred from the HDMI output of the laptop to the HDMI input of the FPGA and then display it on an external monitor throught HDMI Out port of FPGA. The board Pynq Z2 has HDMI In and HDMI Out ports. I plan to use the PS for transferring the video into the FPGA, the PL for inverting the colors, and again the PS for reflecting it onto an external monitor. Is that correct?

Comment: You say you can't think of anything, then you explain what you are thinking!  Off topic here in several levels I think.